# Rails: Copying attributes from an object to another using the "attributes" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let model `Quote` have attributes `[price, description]`

Let model `Invoice` have attributes `[price, description, priority]`

Let `invoice` an object from Model `Invoice` with attributes `{price: 10, description: 'lamp', priority: 10}`

```
invoice = {price: 10, description: 'lamp', priority: 10}
```

Let's say I want to copy `invoice` attributes to a new `quote`.

```
quote = Quote.new(invoice.attributes)
```

This raises an error that `priority` does not existe in model `Quote`.

How do I copy `invoice` attributes to a new `quote` but only the attributes that a `quote` can accept?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) only the attributes that `Quote` has:

```
Quote.new(invoice.attributes.select{ |key, _| Quote.attribute_names.include? key })
```

[As noted by @aceofspades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590690/211563) (but not with a dynamic solution), you can use ActiveSupport's [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) as well:

```
Quote.new(invoice.attributes.slice(*Quote.attribute_names))
```

Comment: Not all `attribute_names` should be copied though. `id`, `updated_at` and `created_at` should probably be `nil` at instantiation.

Comment: Passing just the array returns {}, use below one!
Quote.new(invoice.attributes.slice(*Quote.attribute_names))

Comment: @ajay Hi, Your answer is really helpful. I got the same scenario for adding a multiple attributes. so I got an error `undefined method attributes`. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Try to debug what you get  with just *Quote.attribute_names then try to slice attribute(s)as per your need. @Sri

Answer (score 15):

How about the slice method from ActiveSupport?

```
quote = Quote.new(invoice.attributes.slice(:price, :description))
```

or even

```
quote = Quote.new(invoice.attributes.slice(*Quote.accessible_attributes))
```

Comment: `accessible_attributes` seems to have weird behavior, it only returns attributes that were explicitly made so with `attr_accessible`, so by default this won't contain any of the attributes. This, to me, is a bug in Rails though.

Comment: attr_accessible is a really good idea, attribute_names would work as well in your answer.

Comment: I know you *should* but that doesn't mean people do (as was proven Sunday). That said I expected it to return all accessible attributes, not just those explicitly marked as such.

Comment: I do refer to you, but I did not simply "copy" your answer—I modified it as I saw fit, and used a dynamic method of getting the attributes that you didn't originally have. I am also your upvoter.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is something like this:

```
source = invoice.attributes
target = (source.keys & Quote.attribute_names).inject({}) {|target, key| target[key] = source[key]; target }
quote = Quote.new(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_plan = Plan.last  # it contains object we want to convert
new_plan = Addon.new(sample_plan.attributes.except(:id)) # remove that particular column which is not common else you can get attribute errors.
new_plan # you can get the copy object with data in new one.
```